# IOS Why does Initialisation fail with _variable but not with self.variable for NSNumber?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have the following Class:

---- .h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MapperProtocoll.h"

@interface ServiceRequest : NSObject {
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *url;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *postData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *requestId;
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<ServiceMapperDelegate> mapper;

-(id)initWithUrl:(NSString *)url andWithPostdata:(NSString *)postData;

@end
```

------- .m file

```
#import "ServiceRequest.h"

@implementation ServiceRequest

@synthesize url = _url, postData = _postData, requestId = _requestId, mapper = _mapper;

-(id)initWithUrl:(NSString *)url andWithPostdata:(NSString *)postData {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _url = url;
        _postData = postData;
        self.requestId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:-1]; // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Why does 
**self.requestId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:-1];** 
work but 
**_requestId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:-1];** 
throw a runtime error?

Comment: Try to build a minimal program where to isolate the problem. Then, incrementally add functionality back until you find the source of the bug.

Comment: It throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class method `[NSNumber numberWithInt:-1]` is returning an autoreleased value. When you use the synthesized setter method, the value gets retained by the setter. When you bypass the setter, there is no retain... So as soon as the autorelease pool is drained you have a dangling pointer.

Comment: ...assuming he's not using ARC :)